QML: How to use custom model with runtime determined constructor parameters?
I have a board game with numbered tiles positioned in a square grid. The board uses GridView with custom GameBoard model (GameBoardModel as exported to QML) inherited from QAbstractListModel. The game in it's standard form uses a 4x4 tile grid because that's how many (16) tiles the default constructor of the model creates. However I thought of making some sort of a combobox that would allow choosing the board size, which will then be generated and the game begins.
Now the problem is that I don't see an obvious way to send a number (or call a function) from QML which will proceed to generate a model with desired parameters, load that into QML and update the view.
I've tried creating a separate button and using the dimension property of my model to set dimension to a new value via MouseArea's onClicked and writing _gameboard.model.dimension = 5 (where _gameboard is the id of GameBoard QML type which uses GameBoardModel), but I still couldn't figure out how to properly update my model. I've tried creating some sort of reloadModel method which essentially creates a new list of tiles with new numbers and that would be called after every update of dimension, but even after calling dataChanged it only displayed the old number of elements which is 16 and not 25 (not counting one intentionally hidden).
C++
part of gameboard.h

class GameBoard : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int dimension READ dimension WRITE setDimension NOTIFY dimensionChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int hiddenElementValue READ boardSize NOTIFY hiddenElementChanged)

public:
    static constexpr size_t defaultPuzzleDimension = 4;
    GameBoard(QObject* parent = nullptr, const size_t boardDimension = defaultPuzzleDimension);

    size_t dimension() const;
    void setDimension(size_t newDimension);
    size_t boardSize() const;

signals:
    void dimensionChanged(const size_t newDimension);
    void hiddenElementChanged(int newHiddenElementValue);

private:
    std::vector<Tile> m_rawBoard;
    size_t m_dimension;
    size_t m_boardSize;
    void reloadModel();

}

part of gameboard.cpp

size_t GameBoard::dimension() const
{
    return m_dimension;
}

void GameBoard::setDimension(size_t newDimension)
{
    m_dimension = newDimension;
    reloadModel();
    emit dimensionChanged(m_dimension);
    emit hiddenElementChanged(m_boardSize);
}

size_t GameBoard::boardSize() const
{
    return m_boardSize;
}

void GameBoard::reloadModel()
{
    m_rawBoard.clear();

    m_boardSize = m_dimension * m_dimension;
    m_rawBoard.resize(m_boardSize);
    std::iota(m_rawBoard.begin(),m_rawBoard.end(),1);
    shuffle();

    dataChanged(createIndex(0,0),createIndex(m_boardSize,0));

}

QML
main.qml

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: 680
    height: 440
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Item {
        id: _firstTile
        width: 0.5 * root.width
        height: 0.1 * root.height
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        Tile {
            radius: 30
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.topMargin: 0.05 * parent.height
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0.05 * parent.height
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    _gameboard.model.dimension = 5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Item {
        width: root.width
        height: 0.9 * root.height
        anchors.top: _firstTile.bottom
    GameBoard {
        id: _gameboard
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    }

}

GameBoard.qml

import QtQuick 2.0
import Game 1.0

GridView {
    id: root
    model: GameBoardModel {

    }

    cellHeight: height / root.model.dimension
    cellWidth: width / root.model.dimension

    delegate: Item {
        id: _backgroundDelegate
        width: root.cellWidth
        height: root.cellHeight
        visible: display != root.model.hiddenElementValue
        Tile {
            displayText: display
            anchors.fill: _backgroundDelegate
            anchors.margins: 3
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    root.model.move(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Just glanced at your code; setting/binding the dimension property of your GameBoardModel is the right approach but it seems to me you simply forgot to emit the signals to tell your view the size changed. Remove dataChanged from reloadModel (it is going to be redundant) and instead surround the code by beginResetModel/endResetModel and I think it should do the trick.

Yep, that fixed the view and it works as I expected. I never knew there was a special reset signal like this.

The answer provided by Atmo in the comments is to use beginResetModel and endResetModel signals.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
